# how to add content to first empty div or insert after if not empty using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following content...

```
              <div class="sectionA"></div>
              <div class="sectionA"></div>
              <div class="sectionA"></div>
              <div class="sectionA"></div>
```

First, I need to append content to the first empty div.... So I attempted this:

```
              if(".sectionA").is(":empty"))
              {
                   alert("empty div")
                   $(this).append(value);
              }else // if no available empty divs then insert after last div
              {
                   $(".sectionA:last").after("<div>"+value+"</div>");
              }
```

This logic is not working and the alert("empty div") test never gets trigger and I know there are empty divs as verified through Firebug.. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you put your code on [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) it'll tell you what's wrong. This is the very first step before StackOverflow.

Comment: Elclanrs, i know the code is wrong, I need ideas on better ways to make it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
if ( $(".sectionA").is(":empty") )
// ^ ^ You're missing the parentheses & dollar sign.
```

---

However, your logic is flawed. Use this instead:

```
var $sections = $(".sectionA");
var $empty = $sections.filter(':empty');

if ( $empty.length ) {
    $empty.first().append(value);
} else {
    $sections.last().after('<div>' + value + '</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append content to the first empty div. you missed `$` sign in `if` condition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".sectionA:first").is(":empty"))
  {
       alert("empty div")
       $(this).append(value);
  }else // if no available empty divs then insert after last div
  {
       $(".sectionA:last").after("<div>"+value+"</div>");
  } 
});
```

So after that you will gets `alert("empty div")` test trigger. after that you can perform your logic to append value.